# Analytical six-bar linkage trajectory solution

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, linkage

Six-bar linkage is shown on the image:
[image: Six-bar linkage]

It has one degree of freedom, so if one of the variables is constrained, it's possible to calculate the positions of all the joints. In this specific case the point C is of interest. It is required to derive a function which describes trajectory of point $C$ (red line on image 2), as $x = f(y)$. Constant values are positions of fixed joints $A$, $H$, $G$ and links' lengths $L_{AB}, L_{BC}, L_{FD}, L_{FE}, L_{GE}, L_{HF}$.

[image: Trajectory to be found]

What I *can* do, is assume the angle $\phi_1$ and then use trigonometry to derive positions of points $F$, $E$, $D$, $B$ and finally, $C$. The math behind that is next:

> Define:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> R(\phi)&=[\cos\phi, \sin\phi], \arctan(A) = \arctan(A_y/A_x) \\
> F&=H+L_{HF}R(\phi_1) \\
> \phi_2&=\arctan(FG) \\
> \phi_3&=\arccos\left(\frac{|FG|^2+L_{FE}^2-L_{GE}^2}{2|FG|L_{FE}}\right) \\
> D&=F+L_{FD}R(\phi_2-\phi_3) \\
> \phi_4&=\arctan(AD) \\
> \phi_5&=\arccos\left(\frac{|AD|^2+L_{AB}^2-L_{BD}^2}{2|AD|L_{AB}}\right) \\
> B&=A+L_{AB}R(\phi_4-\phi_5) \\
> C&=B+\frac{L_{BC}}{L_{BD}}BD
> \end{align}$$

That wasn't too hard to derive. Now, the real problem is, *angle $\phi_1$ is unknown*, instead the $y$ coordinate of point $C$ is given.

What I can think of, is combing all the equations into one, expressing $C_y=f^1(\phi_1)$ and trying to inverse the function into $\phi_1=f^2(C_y)$. That way I could pass $C_y$ to $f^2$, get the angle $\phi_1$, pass it to the initial formulas and get $C_x$ as the result. But this seems nearly impossible. I can write down the equation for $C_y$ and it will have just 4 summands, but those will contain sines of $\phi_{2-5}$ which in their turn are arctan or arccos of fractions which contain other angles which are again some invert function of other huge expression... Expression for $\phi_2$ isn't very big, but for $\phi_3$ it's enormous and $\phi_4$ is getting out of my hands. Inverting all that is something I can't imagine.

Are there any sane methods to calculate the six-bar linkage and get an analytic solution for the trajectory?

Comment: Irs much easier if you express it as vectors and matrices or imaginary numbers (wich adnittedly is just a fancy way to say 2d vectors)

Comment: @joojaa It already is all vectors and rotation matrices, isn't it?

Comment: Not really since your doing it with trig, inverting the trig is hard. Just leave the trig out entirely and hide it in the matrix elements.

Comment: @joojaa hello. Sorry to bother you after such a long while... Had to drop the project due to personal reasons and now I'm giving it a second life. Can you please elaborate your answer about matrices and imaginary numbers?